# independent Menus in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have made a main page on wordpress with a specific menu for that page and when I redirected to another page I need a totally different menu in the header but appears the same menu of the main page,I tried with

```
register_nav_menu( 'primary', __( 'Default', 'patti' ) );
register_nav_menu( 'navegacion-cabecera', __( 'Menu Cabecera', 'patti' ) );
```

but don´t works.

Thank you.

Comment: can you elaborate on `but don´t works.`?

Comment: on the main page to click a link that redirects me to the second page but the menu of the main page still displayed in the second page

Comment: Well that is probably because you have the same template for the two pages, where you use the same menu.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your responses, I found the solution in a plugin called Page Specific Menu Items, the plugin allows to hide the items you do not want to be viewed on a specific page